# Append PDF to a Signed PDF

Tags: pdf, itext, digital-signature

I need to append a pdf file to a digital signed pdf file, keeping valid the signature ...maybe using revision? ...using iTextSharp? How can I do it?

Please help me with some sample.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Increment Update to do that, as long as the original signature allows you.

Take look at the document:

http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/download/attachments/52658564/Acrobat_DigitalSignatures_in_PDF.pdf?version=1&modificationDate=1269905473000

on Page 8 you will find what you want.

Comment: Document is now at

https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/etk_deprecated/tools/DigSig/Acrobat_DigitalSignatures_in_PDF.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You can't as that invalidates the whole point of digital signatures, namely to detect when something exactly as you describe occurs and therefore ensure the validity of the original document. To do as you want, you will need to add the extra PDF to the unsigned original PDF and then resign the new conglomerate PDF.

Comment: ...but is there a way to keep revision insiede pdf?
so i will have 
rev 1 with valid signature
...add pdf...
rev 2 with invalid signature
...I resign...
rev 3 with valid signature

Comment: No, there is not. Signed PDF documents are tamper proof. Only the original signer can modify the document and resign.

Comment: I found a solution. Yes PDF support revision history embedded.

Comment: @Andrea: Care to share your answer? I was interested too! You can answer your own question and accept it so more people can benefit from the hive mind :)