# How to make an incremental update to a PDF

Tags: pdf, itext

I need to make an incremental update (add some existing pdf pages)  to an signed pdf, making the included signature still be valid (that cover the first page).

I've seen some post's telling that is possible with PDFStamper (iTextSharp), but I'm unable to find a example out to make it append.

Comment: Your question is very unclear, can you please elaborate?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612253/append-pdf-to-a-signed-pdf

Answer (score 2):

Changing an already signed PDF would sound imply a security leak in the PDF signing functionality/spec. The purpose of signing a PDF is a guarantee to the reader that it has not been altered by anyone other than the original author.

I think your only option is to send extra pages in a seperate PDF, or change the original PDF and have it re-signed.

Comment: To underline @yms' point: for an overview of allowed and disallowed changes look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16711745/1729265).