# How to add blank pages in exist PDF in java?

Tags: java, itext

I have normal PDF file, i want to insert blank pages at the end of PDF using `itext LIBRARY`, without disturbing the PDF contents.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried to import the PDF page by page, insert blank pages when needed, and stitch all back together?

Comment: i have tried this http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=99 but i want to insert pages in exist PDF without disturbing existing content.

Comment: What do you mean by "disturbing the content"?

Comment: And please try to spell it correctly, it's iText, not `ITEXT LIBRARY`, nor `itext LIBRARY` :)

Comment: suppose i have "10" pages in my PDF, i want to add "1" more in it.after adding pages become "11" like wise m looking for this.

Comment: so you want the page numbering to be updated too?

Comment: yes i thing now u got my requirement

Comment: Then iText, and PDF in general, is not the correct tool/format for what you intend to do. PDF is a publication format, not an edition format.

Comment: @alexisPigeon after our satisfactory edition we can publish it, first step is edition.am now in edition phase.:)

Comment: There's a flaw in you process if it consists of creating AND later editing a PDF file. It should only consist of a creation phase.

Comment: @Alexis Pigeon i just want to add blank pages at the end of uploaded pdf.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer by Dinup Kandel is wrong because it's about creating a document from scratch.

The answer by NK123 is *very wrong* because it uses `PdfWriter`/`PdfImportedPage` to concatenate documents. That example assumes that all pages in the original document have the size A4. This won't always be the case. As documented, this also throws away all interactivity.

The only good answer looks like this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
stamper.insertPage(reader.getNumberOfPages() + 1, reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(1));
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

If `src` refers to a document with 10 pages, the code above will add an extra blank 11th page, using the same page size as the first page.

Comment: That's not a good attitude. It means you're not willing to learn something for yourself, but counting on other people to help you instead. A real master teaches pupils by asking them questions, not by answering theirs. This wisdom goes back to the age of Socrates. I fear I'm not a real master if I continue answering questions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710439/how-to-add-blank-page-in-digitally-signed-pdf-using-java 
is this possible?i thing no, but wanted to confirm it from your side?

Comment: I upvoted mkl's answer. You're trying to do something that invalidates the signature.

Comment: Yes.that's what i want to get from u.Thank you for your support.And thanks a lot for your itext library.

Comment: You are welcome to look at [Bruno's book](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf) if you'd like. (Moving this resource to a comment).

Answer (score 0):

well i have searched the answer and found something like this but don't know if it will work or not

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        // step 1
        Document document = new Document();
        // step 2
        PdfWriter writer
            = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(RESULT));
        // step 3
        document.open();
        // step 4
        document.add(new Paragraph("This page will NOT be followed by a blank page!"));
        document.newPage();
        // we don't add anything to this page: newPage() will be ignored
        document.newPage();
        document.add(new Paragraph("This page will be followed by a blank page!"));
        document.newPage();
        writer.setPageEmpty(false);
        document.newPage();
        document.add(new Paragraph("The previous page was a blank page!"));
        // step 5
        document.close();

    }
```

Comment: i have this.http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=99

Comment: hasn't  this code work for you.

Comment: no :( this example creating new pdf. and disturbing the existing content.

Comment: You may have to create a new Pdf ->> Copy contents of old Pdf into it ->> Add new page at the end ->> Save new pdf with the same name.

Comment: ok, u want me to copy paste all content, u dont thing it takes to much time for large files.?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there any way to edit PDF after once generated.

Comment: You can use apache pdf box also for adding the page.
sample reference:
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(existingPDFPath));
PDPage blankPage = new PDPage();
document.addPage(blankPage);
 ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             document.save(outputStream);
             document.close();