# itext pdf multiple displays of a signature

Tags: pdf, itext, digital-signature

I did my research around this topic, I understand in many countries there are legal reasons of not having this. But I have a requirement and need to have display for an external signature on each page. Any working approach/snippet will be highly appreciated.

Also is it possible to help annotations on each page for an existing signature? If yes, any code snippet will be helpful.

Comment: *I understand in many countries there are legal reasons of not having this. But I have a requirement and need to have display for an external signature on each page.* In other words: you want to do something that will be in violation of ISO-32000-2. Or, you want to create a PDF that won't be a valid PDF 2.0 file. If that's what you want, you need to use software that doesn't obey the specs. In that case: don't expect an answer from iText developers.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Unfortunately regulations of all the countries are not as quickly updated as technology.

Comment: Have you actually seen a PDF that looks like what you are asking for?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Oh yes, its not uncommon. Checkout Appendix: Multiple appearances of a signature at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37027579/how-to-associate-a-previous-signature-in-a-new-signature-field but I am experimenting with itext 5, couldn't make it work.

Comment: @AbhinavParashar As you add a link to that answer and couldn't make it work, where did you get stuck? It should be a fairly straight forward port of the code in the *Doing it in iText 5* section of the answer. That been said, if you merely need to *"have display for an external signature on each page"*, why not simply add such visual display on each page as regular content instead of trying to make a PDF AcroForm signature for that? That way you have a *"display"* on each page without any issues with the PDF format or iText.