# Need to add a new page to a pdf document that already has a digital signature

Tags: javascript, itext, adobe-reader

i need to add a new page when there is no more space on the last page of the document i have been seen the digital signare book of itext and it says the i can't be just using the insertPage() method and that's how i do now so the digital signatures get broken so the book says.

> NOTE: Be aware that ‘page adding actions are allowed’ doesn’t mean you can use the insertPage() method. This message refers to page template instantiation as described in the Adobe Acrobat JavaScript Reference Manual, which is out of scope in this paper.

but i can't find how to add the new page with javascript and itext any of you has the same problem that can help me i really need a new page without signs get broken

can't find the code of java script and integrate with itext I foud this but is not working:

```
String js = "var aTemplates = this.templates;"
          + "aTemplates[0].spawn({nPage: 0, bRename: true, bOverlay: false});";

var a = this.getTemplate("MyTemplate");
a.spawn (this.pageNums);
```

and this one

```
//get the array of the template object for the PDF;
var aTemplates = this.templates;
// create a new page from the first template placing it at the end of the PDF and renaming the fields;
// rename the fields, do not overlay;
aTemplates[0].spawn({nPage: 0, bRename: true, bOverlay: false});
```

then i use itext

these two different ways of use javascript but it's not working, not adding new page at the end of the document.

1. PdfAction.javaScript(js, stamper.getWriter());
2. stamper.addJavaScript(js);

Comment: Please put your code in a code block.

Comment: You're asking something that is impossible. Also: in no universe is it a good idea to add a new page to an already signed PDF document.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add blank page in digitally signed pdf using java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710439/how-to-add-blank-page-in-digitally-signed-pdf-using-java) As answered there, adding pages to signed PDFs is not allowed unless your originally signed PDF has been prepared with named page templates.

Comment: but i see on digitalsignature book from itext that says:

NOTE: Be aware that ‘page adding actions are allowed’ doesn’t mean you can use the insertPage() method. This message refers to page template instantiation as described in the Adobe Acrobat JavaScript Reference Manual, which is out of scope in this paper. so how can i use page template of adobe acrobat javascript to add a new page from itex

Comment: Has *your originally signed PDF been prepared with named page templates* or not? If it has, I can show a way. If not, adding pages is not allowed.

Comment: the problem is that i dont know how to add named page templates to my pdf document can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: the problem is that i dont know how to add named page templates to my pdf document can you tell me how to do it? @mkl

Comment: Your comments and your original question seem to indicates that your original documents do not have any page templates added to them. Thus, you cannot make use of them. To make use of such templates, they must have been added before the first signature is added to the document.

Comment: yes you're right i wanted to know how to add the template to my document before the first signature but i cant find how to added it with itext before my document is signed can you provided me any link or document where i can find how to do it with javascript and itext before first sign thanks alot @mkl

Comment: I know I had some ancient code in which I experimented with page templates. I won't have time to search and dust off that code before next week, though.

Comment: ok thanks whenever you have time could you post it or send it please @mkl thank you

Comment: I just checked my old code in which I played around with template. It still works with the recent iText 5.5.x (after package name adaption, obviously), but it looks like Adobe Reader has stopped considering spawning of page templates to be allowed in signed documents. :(

Comment: too bad for adobe reader,  but i appreciate your help i think i would consider treat the document before sending to sign to add the page and the document still mantein the second sign valid thanks @mkl

Comment: Oops, I have to take that back. It looks as if Adobe simply is not happy with the way my code from back then spawns the page templates. If Adobe Reader does it itself, the signature is not broken.

Comment: Hhmmm, Adobe Reader requires a certain compressed x-object stream to have the same size as if it had compressed it itself. Unfortunately I don't know how to predict that size and enforce it on my side.

Comment: @CarlosCuellar If you are interested in experimenting, I added the code in question as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer shows 90% of a solution of the problem up to the problem mentioned in my comments to the original question.*

### Helper class for page template handling

Years ago, when Adobe Reader started to consider a signature broken as soon as additional pages with new content were added to the PDF, I experimented with page template instantiation. As it turns out, that code could easily be adapted to the current 5.5.x iText versions (and additionally to Java generics). I have not tried adaption to iText 7 yet.

Due to limited visibility of iText API methods used here, this class has to be put into the package `com.itextpdf.text.pdf`. Alternatively this class may be changed to make considerable use of reflection magic.

```
public class PdfStamperHelper
{
    public static final PdfName TEMPLATES = new PdfName("Templates");
    public static final PdfName TEMPLATE = new PdfName("Template"); 
    public static final PdfName TEMPLATE_INSTANTIATED = new PdfName("TemplateInstantiated"); 

    /**
     * This method names a given page. The page in question already has
     * to exist in the original document the given PdfStamper works on.
     */
    public static void createTemplate(PdfStamper pdfStamper, String name, int page) throws IOException, DocumentException
    {
        PdfDictionary pageDic = pdfStamper.stamper.reader.getPageNRelease(page);
        if (pageDic != null && pageDic.getIndRef() != null)
        {
            HashMap<String, PdfObject> namedPages = getNamedPages(pdfStamper);
            namedPages.put(name, pageDic.getIndRef());
            storeNamedPages(pdfStamper);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method hides a given visible named page.
     */
    public static void hideTemplate(PdfStamper pdfStamper, String name) throws IOException, DocumentException
    {
        HashMap<String, PdfObject> namedPages = getNamedPages(pdfStamper);
        PdfObject object = namedPages.get(name);
        if (object == null)
            throw new DocumentException("Document contains no visible template " + name + '.');

        namedPages.remove(name);
        storeNamedPages(pdfStamper);

        if (removePage(pdfStamper, (PRIndirectReference)pdfStamper.stamper.reader.getCatalog().get(PdfName.PAGES), (PRIndirectReference) object))
        {
            pdfStamper.stamper.reader.pageRefs.reReadPages();
            // TODO: correctAcroFieldPages 
        }
        PdfDictionary pageDict = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.getPdfObject(object);
        if (pageDict != null)
        {
            pdfStamper.stamper.markUsed(pageDict);
            pageDict.remove(PdfName.PARENT);
            pageDict.remove(PdfName.B);
            pageDict.put(PdfName.TYPE, TEMPLATE);
        }

        HashMap<String, PdfObject> templates = getNamedTemplates(pdfStamper);
        templates.put(name, object);
        storeNamedTemplates(pdfStamper);
    }

    /**
     * This method returns a template dictionary.
     */
    public static PdfDictionary getTemplate(PdfStamper pdfStamper, String name) throws DocumentException
    {
        HashMap<String, PdfObject> namedTemplates = getNamedTemplates(pdfStamper);
        PdfObject object = (PdfObject) namedTemplates.get(name);
        if (object == null) {
            HashMap<String, PdfObject> namedPages = getNamedPages(pdfStamper);
            object = namedPages.get(name);
        }
        return (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.getPdfObject(object);
    }

    /**
     * This method spawns a template inserting it at the given page number.
     */
    public static void spawnTemplate(PdfStamper pdfStamper, String name, int pageNumber) throws DocumentException, IOException
    {
        PdfDictionary template = getTemplate(pdfStamper, name);
        if (template == null)
            throw new DocumentException("Document contains no template " + name + '.');

        PdfReader reader = pdfStamper.stamper.reader;

        // contRef: reference to the content stream of the spawned page;
        // it only inserts the template XObject
        PRIndirectReference contRef = reader.addPdfObject(getTemplateStream(name, reader.getPageSize(template)));
        // resRef: reference to resources dictionary containing a /XObject
        // dictionary in turn containing the template XObject resource
        // carrying the actual template content
        PdfDictionary xobjDict = new PdfDictionary();
        xobjDict.put(new PdfName(name), reader.addPdfObject(getFormXObject(reader, template, pdfStamper.stamper.getCompressionLevel(), name)));
        PdfDictionary resources = new PdfDictionary();
        resources.put(PdfName.XOBJECT, xobjDict);
        PRIndirectReference resRef = reader.addPdfObject(resources);

        // page: dictionary of the spawned template page
        PdfDictionary page = new PdfDictionary();
        page.put(PdfName.TYPE, PdfName.PAGE); // not PdfName.TEMPLATE!
        page.put(TEMPLATE_INSTANTIATED, new PdfName(name));
        page.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, contRef);
        page.put(PdfName.RESOURCES, resRef);
        page.mergeDifferent(template); // actually a bit too much. TODO: treat annotations as they should be treated

        PRIndirectReference pref = reader.addPdfObject(page);
        PdfDictionary parent;
        PRIndirectReference parentRef;
        if (pageNumber > reader.getNumberOfPages()) {
            PdfDictionary lastPage = reader.getPageNRelease(reader.getNumberOfPages());
            parentRef = (PRIndirectReference)lastPage.get(PdfName.PARENT);
            parentRef = new PRIndirectReference(reader, parentRef.getNumber());
            parent = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.getPdfObject(parentRef);
            PdfArray kids = (PdfArray)PdfReader.getPdfObject(parent.get(PdfName.KIDS), parent);
            kids.add(pref);
            pdfStamper.stamper.markUsed(kids);
            reader.pageRefs.insertPage(pageNumber, pref);
        }
        else {
            if (pageNumber < 1)
                pageNumber = 1;
            PdfDictionary firstPage = reader.getPageN(pageNumber);
            PRIndirectReference firstPageRef = reader.getPageOrigRef(pageNumber);
            reader.releasePage(pageNumber);
            parentRef = (PRIndirectReference)firstPage.get(PdfName.PARENT);
            parentRef = new PRIndirectReference(reader, parentRef.getNumber());
            parent = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.getPdfObject(parentRef);
            PdfArray kids = (PdfArray)PdfReader.getPdfObject(parent.get(PdfName.KIDS), parent);
            ArrayList<PdfObject> ar = kids.getArrayList();
            int len = ar.size();
            int num = firstPageRef.getNumber();
            for (int k = 0; k < len; ++k) {
                PRIndirectReference cur = (PRIndirectReference)ar.get(k);
                if (num == cur.getNumber()) {
                    ar.add(k, pref);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (len == ar.size())
                throw new RuntimeException("Internal inconsistence.");
            pdfStamper.stamper.markUsed(kids);
            reader.pageRefs.insertPage(pageNumber, pref);
            pdfStamper.stamper.correctAcroFieldPages(pageNumber);
        }
        page.put(PdfName.PARENT, parentRef);
        while (parent != null) {
            pdfStamper.stamper.markUsed(parent);
            PdfNumber count = (PdfNumber)PdfReader.getPdfObjectRelease(parent.get(PdfName.COUNT));
            parent.put(PdfName.COUNT, new PdfNumber(count.intValue() + 1));
            parent = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.getPdfObject(parent.get(PdfName.PARENT));
        }
    }

    //
    // helper methods
    //
    /**
     * This method recursively removes a given page from the given page tree.
     */
    static boolean removePage(PdfStamper pdfStamper, PRIndirectReference pageTree, PRIndirectReference pageToRemove)
    {
        PdfDictionary pageDict = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.getPdfObject(pageTree);
        PdfArray kidsPR = (PdfArray)PdfReader.getPdfObject(pageDict.get(PdfName.KIDS));
        if (kidsPR != null) {
            ArrayList<PdfObject> kids = kidsPR.getArrayList();
            boolean removed = false;
            for (int k = 0; k < kids.size(); ++k){
                PRIndirectReference obj = (PRIndirectReference)kids.get(k);
                if (pageToRemove.getNumber() == obj.getNumber() && pageToRemove.getGeneration() == obj.getGeneration())
                {
                    kids.remove(k);
                    pdfStamper.stamper.markUsed(pageTree);
                    removed = true;
                    break;
                }
                else if (removePage(pdfStamper, (PRIndirectReference)obj, pageToRemove))
                {
                    removed = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (removed)
            {
                PdfNumber count = (PdfNumber) PdfReader.getPdfObjectRelease(pageDict.get(PdfName.COUNT));
                pageDict.put(PdfName.COUNT, new PdfNumber(count.intValue() + 1));
                pdfStamper.stamper.markUsed(pageTree);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the uncompressed bytes of a content PDF object.
     */
    static byte[] pageContentsToArray(PdfReader reader, PdfObject contents, RandomAccessFileOrArray file) throws IOException{
        if (contents == null)
            return new byte[0];
        if (file == null)
            file = reader.getSafeFile();
        ByteArrayOutputStream bout = null;
        if (contents.isStream()) {
            return PdfReader.getStreamBytes((PRStream)contents, file);
        }
        else if (contents.isArray()) {
            PdfArray array = (PdfArray)contents;
            ArrayList<PdfObject> list = array.getArrayList();
            bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            for (int k = 0; k < list.size(); ++k) {
                PdfObject item = PdfReader.getPdfObjectRelease(list.get(k));
                if (item == null || !item.isStream())
                    continue;
                byte[] b = PdfReader.getStreamBytes((PRStream)item, file);
                bout.write(b);
                if (k != list.size() - 1)
                    bout.write('\n');
            }
            return bout.toByteArray();
        }
        else
            return new byte[0];
    }

    /**
     * This method returns a PDF stream object containing a copy of the
     * contents of the given template page with the given name.<br>
     * To make Acrobat 9 happy with this template XObject when checking
     * for signature validity, the /Size has to be changed to be the size
     * of the stream that would have been generated by Acrobat itself
     * when spawning the given template.
     */
    static PdfStream getFormXObject(PdfReader reader, PdfDictionary page, int compressionLevel, String name) throws IOException {
        Rectangle pageSize = reader.getPageSize(page);
        final PdfLiteral MATRIX = new PdfLiteral("[1 0 0 1 " + -getXOffset(pageSize) + " " + -getYOffset(pageSize) + "]");
        PdfDictionary dic = new PdfDictionary();
        dic.put(PdfName.RESOURCES, PdfReader.getPdfObjectRelease(page.get(PdfName.RESOURCES)));
        dic.put(PdfName.TYPE, PdfName.XOBJECT);
        dic.put(PdfName.SUBTYPE, PdfName.FORM);
        dic.put(PdfName.BBOX, page.get(PdfName.MEDIABOX));
        dic.put(PdfName.MATRIX, MATRIX);
        dic.put(PdfName.FORMTYPE, PdfReaderInstance.ONE);
        dic.put(PdfName.NAME, new PdfName(name));

        PdfStream stream;
        PdfObject contents = PdfReader.getPdfObjectRelease(page.get(PdfName.CONTENTS));
        byte bout[] = null;
        if (contents != null)
            bout = pageContentsToArray(reader, contents, reader.getSafeFile());
        else
            bout = new byte[0];
        byte[] embedded = new byte[bout.length + 4];
        System.arraycopy(bout, 0, embedded, 2, bout.length);
        embedded[0] = 'q';
        embedded[1] = 10;
        embedded[embedded.length - 2] = 'Q';
        embedded[embedded.length - 1] = 10;
        stream = new PdfStream(embedded);
        stream.putAll(dic);
        stream.flateCompress(compressionLevel);
        PdfObject filter = stream.get(PdfName.FILTER);
        if (filter != null && !(filter instanceof PdfArray))
            stream.put(PdfName.FILTER, new PdfArray(filter));
        return stream;
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the content stream object for a spawned
     * template.
     */
    static PdfStream getTemplateStream(String name, Rectangle pageSize)
    {
        int x = getXOffset(pageSize);
        int y = getYOffset(pageSize);
        String content = "q 1 0 0 1 " + x + " " + y + " cm /" + name + " Do Q";
        return new PdfStream(PdfEncodings.convertToBytes(content, null));
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the center x offset for the given page rectangle.
     */
    static int getXOffset(Rectangle pageSize)
    {
        return Math.round((pageSize.getLeft() + pageSize.getRight()) / 2);
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the center y offset for the given page rectangle.
     */
    static int getYOffset(Rectangle pageSize)
    {
        return Math.round((pageSize.getTop() + pageSize.getBottom()) / 2);
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the /Names name dictionary of the document; if
     * the document does not have one yet, it generates one.<br>
     * Beware! If the document contains a name dictionary as an indirect
     * object, the dictionary shall be written to but once; this /includes/
     * writes by the {@link PdfStamper}.
     */
    static PdfDictionary getNameDictionary(PdfStamper pdfStamper)
    {
        PdfDictionary catalog = pdfStamper.stamper.reader.getCatalog();
        PdfDictionary names = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.getPdfObject(catalog.get(PdfName.NAMES), catalog);
        if (names == null) {
            names = new PdfDictionary();
            catalog.put(PdfName.NAMES, names);
            pdfStamper.stamper.markUsed(catalog);
        }
        return names;
    }

    final static Map<PdfStamper, HashMap<String, PdfObject>> namedPagesByStamper = new HashMap<>();

    static HashMap<String, PdfObject> getNamedPages(PdfStamper pdfStamper) throws DocumentException
    {
        if (namedPagesByStamper.containsKey(pdfStamper))
            return namedPagesByStamper.get(pdfStamper);

        final PdfDictionary nameDictionary = getNameDictionary(pdfStamper);
        PdfObject pagesObject = PdfReader.getPdfObjectRelease(nameDictionary.get(PdfName.PAGES));
        if (pagesObject != null && !(pagesObject instanceof PdfDictionary))
            throw new DocumentException("Pages name dictionary is neither a PdfDictionary nor null");
        HashMap<String, PdfObject> namesMap = PdfNameTree.readTree((PdfDictionary)pagesObject);
        namedPagesByStamper.put(pdfStamper, namesMap);
        return namesMap;
    }

    static void storeNamedPages(PdfStamper pdfStamper) throws IOException
    {
        if (namedPagesByStamper.containsKey(pdfStamper))
        {
            final HashMap<String, PdfObject> pages = namedPagesByStamper.get(pdfStamper);
            final PdfDictionary nameDictionary = getNameDictionary(pdfStamper);
            pdfStamper.stamper.markUsed(nameDictionary);
            if (pages.isEmpty())
                nameDictionary.remove(PdfName.PAGES);
            else {
                final PdfDictionary tree = PdfNameTree.writeTree(pages, pdfStamper.stamper);
                nameDictionary.put(PdfName.PAGES, pdfStamper.stamper.addToBody(tree).getIndirectReference());
            }
        }
    }

    final static Map<PdfStamper, HashMap<String, PdfObject>> namedTemplatesByStamper = new HashMap<>();

    static HashMap<String, PdfObject> getNamedTemplates(PdfStamper pdfStamper) throws DocumentException
    {
        if (namedTemplatesByStamper.containsKey(pdfStamper))
            return namedTemplatesByStamper.get(pdfStamper);

        final PdfDictionary nameDictionary = getNameDictionary(pdfStamper);
        PdfObject templatesObject = PdfReader.getPdfObjectRelease(nameDictionary.get(TEMPLATES));
        if (templatesObject != null && !(templatesObject instanceof PdfDictionary))
            throw new DocumentException("Templates name dictionary is neither a PdfDictionary nor null");
        HashMap<String, PdfObject> templatesMap = PdfNameTree.readTree((PdfDictionary)templatesObject);
        namedTemplatesByStamper.put(pdfStamper, templatesMap);
        return templatesMap;
    }

    static void storeNamedTemplates(PdfStamper pdfStamper) throws IOException
    {
        if (namedTemplatesByStamper.containsKey(pdfStamper))
        {
            final HashMap<String, PdfObject> templates = namedTemplatesByStamper.get(pdfStamper);
            final PdfDictionary nameDictionary = getNameDictionary(pdfStamper);
            pdfStamper.stamper.markUsed(nameDictionary);
            if (templates.isEmpty())
                nameDictionary.remove(TEMPLATES);
            else {
                final PdfDictionary tree = PdfNameTree.writeTree(templates, pdfStamper.stamper);
                nameDictionary.put(TEMPLATES, pdfStamper.stamper.addToBody(tree).getIndirectReference());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*([PdfStamperHelper.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfStamperHelper.java))*

### Using the helper class

The helper class assumes you already have a PDF and want to make some page in it a named page template or instantiate an existing named template.

You can make an existing page a named template like this:

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(resource);
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, target, '\0', true);
PdfStamperHelper.createTemplate(pdfStamper, "template", 1);
pdfStamper.close();
```

*([BasicTemplating.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/template/BasicTemplating.java) test `testNameTest`)*

The page does remain visible. If you don't want that, hide it using `PdfStamperHelper.hideTemplate` after naming.

You can spawn an existing template like this:

```
pdfReader = new PdfReader(...);
pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, target, '\0', true);
PdfStamperHelper.spawnTemplate(pdfStamper, "template", 1);
pdfStamper.close();
```

*([BasicTemplating.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/template/BasicTemplating.java) test `testNameSpawnTest`)*

### Issue in concert with Adobe Reader

I took a PDF, created a named page template in it, and signed that PDF.

Then I spawned the named template using the code above, cf. [BasicTemplating.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/template/BasicTemplating.java) test `testSpawnPdfaNamedSigned`, and then inspected the result in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC, I unfortunately saw

[image: Screenshot "Signature is invalid"]

My older Acrobat Pro 9.5 after pressing "Compute Modifications List" is even aware that only a page template has been instantiated but still calls the signature INVALID:

[image: Screenshot "INVALID" and "1 page(s) generated from templates"]

---

Experiments showed that Adobe Acrobat Reader executes one test that does not make any sense in the light of the PDF specification: It expects the page template form xobject to have the same **Size** entry value after compression (!!) as if it was compressed by the Reader itself. As different implementations of the deflate compression can result in different stream sizes (iText's implementation in the case at hand created a stream 3 bytes shorter), I have no idea yet how to generically pass this test.

After patching the specific stream's **Size** entry in the PDF generated above from 159 to 162, Adobe Acrobat Reader shows:

[image: Screenshot no "Signature is invalid" anymore]

(The validity is unknown because revocation information had not been added in time.)