# Check with PDFBox v2.x.x if a PDF Form was changed after signing

Tags: java, pdf, itext, digital-signature, pdfbox

I hava a pdf form. How to check with PDFBox v2.x.x if a pdf form was changed after the signature was added? I think the equivalent in itext 4.2.1 is the signaturecoverswholedocument method. The only thing i could find was how to check the signature itself:

```
        if (signerInformation.verify(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().build(certificateHolder))) {
```

Comment: iText 4.2.1 was never released by iText Software.

Comment: I don't have a perfect answer, only a hint: call `getByteRange()` on the `PDSignature` objects (read in the PDF specification what the values mean), then compare these values with the size of your PDF.

Comment: @Tilman that should suffice as an actual answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No perfect answer, but a strategy to make a decision:

```
try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(infile), password))
{
    for (PDSignature sig : document.getSignatureDictionaries())
    {
        int[] byteRange = sig.getByteRange();
        System.out.println("byteRange: " + Arrays.toString(byteRange));
        System.out.println("Range max: " + (byteRange[byteRange.length-2] + byteRange[byteRange.length-1]));
        // multiply content length with 2 (because it is in hex in the PDF) and add 2 for < and >
        System.out.println("Content len: " + (sig.getCOSObject().getString(COSName.CONTENTS).length() * 2 + 2));
        System.out.println("File len: " + new File(infile).length());
(...)
```

Now test this with [this file](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12577388/test4.pdf). You'll get this output:

```
byteRange: [0, 192, 10094, 162062]
Range max: 172156
Content len: 9902
File len: 172156
```

The data that is signed starts at 0 with len 192, then the signature , then the rest of the data at 10094 with len 162062. You'll notice that 10094 + 162062 == 172156, and 192 + 9902 == 10094.

Of course if there are several signatures it won't look that perfect.

Comment: This essentially is what the *iText signaturecoverswholedocument method* mentioned by the OP does.

Comment: @mkl yeah, I've just seen your answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37490084/how-reliable-is-itexts-signaturecoverswholedocument-vs-acrobat-reader . Maybe I'll add my solution to the ShowSignature example with a warning that a false result doesn't necessarily mean that the PDF is a fake.

Comment: it works. Would it also be possible to decrypt the (whatsoever) digest stored in the signature with the certifacte from the signatureDictionary, compute a digest from the actual pdffile (within the byteranges) and compare that digest with the decrypted digest?

Comment: I think that is what is done in the ShowSignature example from the source code download.