# IText AllowAssembly and StandardEncryption

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am attempting to digitally sign a pdf document while still allowing for the modification of annotations and allowing the adding and removing of pages using `itextsharp, Version=4.1.6.0`. Below is my current code:

```
var signatureStamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(pdfReader, memoryStream, '\0', null);
signatureStamper.SetEncryption(null, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(certificationBundle.Password), PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING | PdfWriter.ALLOW_MODIFY_ANNOTATIONS | PdfWriter.AllowAssembly, PdfWriter.STANDARD_ENCRYPTION_128);
```

With this configuration however, I am still unable to add and remove pages. Am I Using `PdfWriter.AllowAssembly` incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am attempting to digitally sign a pdf document while still allowing for the modification of annotations and allowing the adding and removing of pages

*Addition or removal of pages* is never allowed for signed documents,  cf. [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16711745/1729265). At most you are allowed to do the following:

> - Adding signature fields
> - Adding or editing annotations
> - Supplying form field values
> - Digitally signing