# Why is my PDPage closed after removing it from its original PDDocument?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am trying to render and attach a new page to an existing PDF:

```
PDDocument withNewPage = renderNewPage();
withNewPage.getPages().forEach(page -> {
  markNeedToBeUpdated( // https://stackoverflow.com/a/56038907/1189885
      page,
      page.getResources(),
      page.getResources().getCOSObject().getDictionary(COSName.XOBJECT)
  );

  withNewPage.removePage(page);
  original.addPage(page);
});
```

This code works, but I get a finalizer warning because I forgot to close `withNewPage`. I added `withNewPage.close()` after this snippet, but now when I try to export the `original` to bytes I get the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: COSStream has been closed and cannot be read. Perhaps its enclosing PDDocument has been closed?
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.checkClosed(COSStream.java:83)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.createRawInputStream(COSStream.java:133)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.visitFromStream(COSWriter.java:1288)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.accept(COSStream.java:416)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.doWriteObject(COSWriter.java:570)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.doWriteObjects(COSWriter.java:496)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.doWriteBody(COSWriter.java:480)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.visitFromDocument(COSWriter.java:1182)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument.accept(COSDocument.java:452)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.write(COSWriter.java:1455)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.saveIncremental(PDDocument.java:1421)
```

I've debugged the `close` call, and the new page itself does not appear in the list of items closed by `withNewPage.close()`, though some `COSStream` objects do.

Why does calling `removePage` not prevent the page (or its stream?) from being closed along with the document it no longer belongs to, and how can I get this merge accomplished cleanly?

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57268163/1189885) regarding this error, but I expected my code to work because I am *removing* the page from the rendered document. Additionally, the documentation for `importPage` says specifically that it should not be applied to generated documents such as this one. I tried it anyway, and I still got the same exception.

Comment: Maybe the removed page had resources that are also used by other pages, e.g. fonts, images, etc.

Comment: The page is still connected to the parent document so you need to detach it before adding it to the original document. Call: `page.setDocument(null);
withNewPage.removePage(page);`

Comment: @Lonzak PDPage doesn't have a setDocument() method

Comment: @TilmanHausherr You are right. Couldn't one could create a new page by copying the data over from the page: `PDPage pageNew = new PDPage();
  pageNew.setContents(page.getContents());
  pageNew.setResources(page.getResources());
  pageNew.setAnnotations(page.getAnnotations());
  pageNew.set...(); withNewPage.removePage(page); 
  original.addPage(pageNew);`

Comment: You're still copying pointers to resources. Only cloning would solve this, but this would bloat the result files (I think we had this for a while) if several pages share the same resources. The best is not to overthink this, and close all files only when all is done and not early.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr That's what I'm doing now, but it makes it difficult-to-impractical to use a functional approach to composing the documents.