# Adding Parafe Field with String and Image in PDF using Spring Boot and PDFBox for Multiple Signatures

Tags: java, spring-boot, pdf, pdfbox

I have a Spring Boot microservice using PDFBox 2.0.28, connected to RabbitMQ for receiving signature requests. I am currently using PDF fields to gather information from clients and sign documents.

After filling and signing the initial set of fields, I would like to be able to fill and sign the document a second time. The reason behind this is to allow the completion of additional fields and signing the document again by another user without compromising the integrity of the first signature.

I successfully accomplished this in the initial version. However, my current objective is to add a parafe field, which includes both a string and an image. The goal is to populate this parafe field with a string and a logo image.

I am seeking guidance on how to achieve this, and I would appreciate it if someone could provide a code example. I am looking to implement a parafe field similar to how other signature platforms like DocuSign handle it.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Have you tried the CreateVisualSignature2 example? This one is more flexible, you can have an image and text.

Comment: Thank you, @TilmanHausherr, but I want to add a field with an image and text without including a signature.

Comment: The use case of electronic signing is that people shouldn't do that.

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16711745/1729265) - adding a field (except a signature field) to a digitally signed PDF is never allowed

Comment: Thankyou , but my current objective is to add a field, which includes both a string and an image or a image. The goal is to populate this field with a string and a logo image or a image.

Comment: *"my current objective is to add a field, which includes both a string and an image or a image."* - First of all, there are no dedicated PDF form fields for images. Signature form fields can have arbitrary appearances, so they may help. And some contexts misuse buttons to carry images. That all being said, adding any non-signature fields to digitally signed PDFs will invalidate the existing signature.

Comment: @mkl In the web application called DocuSign, there is a field labeled 'paraf' that has the appearance of an image. This field can be created empty at the time of sending the signature request. After the first signer fills in the fields and signs the document, the second signer can then fill in and sign this specific field,Is it possible for me to access or create a similar field in some way?

Comment: How about adding multiple (empty) signature fields at the start? Then each signer could sign the field made for them.

Comment: Yes i do that, but my current objective is haw to impliment a field with image in the secend signatur without invalidate the first sgnature, i ned a exemple of code.

Comment: Either you use the signature field of the second signature, or you use an existing non-signature field that can hold an image, or you use an annotation.

Comment: @mkl, yes, that's what I want to do, using an existing non-signature field that can contain an image, or using an annotation.
can you give me an example, thank you.